# Python: How to find trip based on location of people

Tags: python, location, repeat

I have a dataset like this:

```
use_id    time             lat-lon    bin    repeated   
1335     08:05:00          (87,78)    20         1
1335     08:10:00          (87,78)    20         2   
1335     08:15:00          (87,78)    20         3
1335     08:20:00          (88,78)    22         1
1335     08:25:00          (88,78)    22         2
1335     08:30:00          (89,78)    23         1
1335     08:35:00          (89,70)    25         1
1335     08:40:00          (80,78)    26         1
1335     08:45:00          (80,78)    26         2
1335     08:50:00          (80,78)    26         3
1335     08:55:00          (80,78)    26         4
....     ........          .......    ..         .
```

I want to find trips based on bins. Here is the idea: The trip will start when the current bin is different from the next bin.And, after seeing four repeated bin the trip should end on the first repeated bin.

For each trip I want to extract the "lat-lon" and "time" of the start point and end point of the trip. At the end I want to have a list of trips for each distinct "user_id".

For example, here, the trip should start from the last 20 and should finish on the first 26. So, at the end I should have something like this:

[20,26]=[((87,78), 08:15:00), ((80,78), 08:40:00)]

(I my dataset I have more "user_id". Here you can see just one.)

I added the "repeated" column to find the repetition of the bin. I taught maybe it can help me in the process but I don't know how to continue.

Please tell me if it needs more information. Thanks

Comment: You wrote ".And, the trip will end when we see four repeated bins. The trip will end on the first repeated bin. ". This seems contradictory, please clarify what you mean. After how many records would the trip end in your example?

Comment: After seeing four repeated bins the trip should end on the first repeated one.

Comment: You mean "After seeing four repeated bins the trip should end on the next repeated bin." ?

Comment: I'm assuming it means that, taking the above dataset as an example, bin 26 is repeated 4 times, so the code would consider the trip ended on bin 26#2, discarding the last two bin 26.

Comment: No it should be on bin 26#1.

Comment: Can you help me please?

Comment: What form is your dataset? Database, csv, tsv, other...? Is your representation of it accurate, as in it can be copy/pasted and used as-is?

Comment: It is csv. Yes, it is accurate. @AntoineM.